Не считывается буква І, вместо нее знак вопроса
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
string test = Console.ReadLine(); - мне в тест нужно считывать строку и там например "Ні" по украински, и вместо буквы і выводит ?, как пофиксить??

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31328364/when-reading-a-file-i-get-as-input-instead-of-cyrillic-letters похоже на вашу проблему

Вы пытаетесь решить проблему с вводом заданием кодировки вывода, не находите это странным? Закрыл как дубликат, для вас ответ лишь с разницей, что вместо 866 вам нужна Encoding.UTF8. Encoding.RegisterProvider для UTF8 делать не нужно.
